# QWebEngine - get current maximum scroll value

Tags: javascript, qt5, qtwebengine

I'm creating a markdown text editor that has a `QPlainTextEdit` on the left, used to enter the text and a `QWebEngineView` on the right, used to show the preview.

The problem is that I cannot synchronize the `QWebEngineView` scroll position when I scroll the left panel (the `QPlainTextEdit`).
I can programmatically scroll the `QWebEngineView` calling

```
page()->runJavaScript("window.scrollTo(0, y);")
```

but without its current maximum scroll value, I cannot calculate the right value.

So, the question is:

is there a way to get the current `QWebEngineView`'s maximum scroll value? 
An equivalent of a

```
int max = widget->verticalScrollBar()->maximum()
```

in other words.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution.

`document.body.scrollHeight` is what I was looking for so I create a const string:

```
const QString ScrollJavaScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight * %1 / %2);");
```

and after getting the current scroll value and maximum scroll value of the editor (the `QPlainText`):

```
double cP   = m->editor->verticalScrollBar()->value();
double maxP = m->editor->verticalScrollBar()->maximum();
```

I execute the javascript:

```
if( maxP > 0 )
{
    m->preview->page()->runJavaScript(ScrollJavaScript.arg(cP).arg(maxP));
}
```